# Android: When and where to invoke Alarm Service?

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager

I want to keep the **XMPPConnection** open in my application. To achieve that, I thought repeat opening the connection in certain interval of time using `AlarmManager`. But my confusion is when and from where I have to initiate that `AlarmService`.

**Question 1:** If I start that `AlarmService` from the `LaunchActivity`, won't it be scheduled multiple times ?

**Question 2:** If I start that `AlarmService` from any other `Activity` or Service, what happens if the user forcefully killed the app ?

**Question 3:** Creating `AlarmService` for same `PendingIntent` will replace it(or override it) or it will be scheduled as new one ?

Answer (score 1):

You can start your pending intents from launch activity. The key for pending intent is time, so save the time in `UserPrefs` or `local DataBase`. And on every launch, before you going to start next pending intent, call `alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);` to remove the expired intent.